# Integrate SFMC Campaigns with CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud, campaign

Is there a way to map/integrate Campaigns created within Salesforce Marketing Cloud with Campaigns on Salesforce Sales Cloud? Or are these two totally different features.

Can I create a campaign in Sales Cloud, map it to a campaign in SFMC and get the analytics back to Service Cloud?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Totally different features with absolutely no relation to each other.

- Salesforce Campaigns are for actual event management, with direct relation to Campaign Members and Opportunities.
- Marketing Cloud Campaigns are essentially for tagging and categorizing content, it is a classic feature that doesn't serve much purpose or use considering how limited it is.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rain ... Every time I had a hard time explaining this difference during my demos... Your answer is so CRISP n CLEAR (y)